# sqlcmd login to synapse - not workng

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, sqlcmd

I wanted to try to connect to azure synapse from the terminal using sqlcmd which is not happening from my machine.

I did tried this way:

[image]

Even all the input is given but still sqlcmd is throwing one syntax error.

Please correct me where I need to make change. thanks in advance.

sqlcmd is the [commandline utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/get-started-connect-sqlcmd) from Microsoft to connection.

**Update1:**
Different form of tries I did with possible available options:
[image]

**Update2:**
Tried with suggestions given by @SaiVamsi
[image]
But look like default is even not working out.

Comment: hi @Indrajeet Gour, can you provide shell script. what you tried

Comment: Hi @SaiVamsi, sqlcmd is the command line utility, I tried directly from terminal no other shell script involved.

Comment: What is `-lrt` in your command line? Clearly it thinks that's `-l rt`

Comment: @JamesZ as mentioned, I did tried with other options as well, let me know if you wanted to something very specific one to try with.

Comment: The correct parameter is ´-l 5`  -- so again, where did this `-lrt` come from? Is that part of your host, username, password etc? Or are you just adding it there?

Comment: @JamesZ I did tried your ways as well, I have updated the questions with few more tries, would you please help if possible!!

Comment: I did not ask you to try "my ways", I'm asking what **IS** that -lrt. Is that part of your **password** or **hostname** or something? It is **not supposed to be there** like the error says

Comment: @JamesZ 100% that is what I also worried about, point is even if I did not even added non of the flags -lrt, it is coming up as default response from the sqlcmd command, we can see from the tries. that is what I have not seen on the internet just happening with me. Is is because of the binary installed on my Redhat machine or sometime else, till not have the concrete answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduce same thing in my environment .I got same output.

[image]

**As per above community document** **you can see its working fine without using -l rt**

```
sqlcmd -S server_name.sql.azuresynapse.net -d database_name -U user_name -P password -I
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Update** :

Use correct parameter  `-l 5` as suggested by  @ James Z

[image]

Comment: Thank you @SaiVamsi for your response, I tried as you mentioned I have updated my question with tries you mentioned, pl correct me if I am missing something more.

Comment: Hi @IndrajeetGour, use this one at the end of code `I -l 5 ` as shown in the update.

Comment: I did tried the same, you can see the same on the update2 mentioned in question